# Can transitive verbs be further broken down?

Tags: verbs, semantics, linguistics, transitive-verbs

Can transitive verbs be further broken down into different types of transitive verbs?

For example, I think there are change of state transitive verbs and stative transitive verbs, and was wondering if there any other types.

Comment: Well, I know there are change of state transitive verbs and stative transitive verbs, I believe...

Comment: There are all kinds of ways you can slice things, depending on what your aim is.  It isn't enough to say that verbs take 0, 1, 2, 3, or however many arguments, because not all N-argument verbs act the same. There’s a difference between making someone supper and making them king, just as one example. You can bet someone a buck they agree. There are ambitransive verbs, and various causative pairs like *lie/lay, sit/set, fall/fell, rise/raise, wring/wrench, drink/drench*. Some causatives require animate subjects, while others don't. All kinds of little things like this.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphosyntactic_alignment), [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb#English_usage), [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causative), [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dative_shift), [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unaccusative_verb), and [all of these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Transitivity_and_valency). There are also impersonal verbs and (some claim) deponent verbs that never occur in the active only in the passive, like *born*.

Comment: Transitivity is really a property of clauses, not verbs. Verbs are not always transitive or always intransitive; they vary considerably in their syntactic possibilities, just as they vary in prepositions and complement types

Comment: Allerton argues that 'a stool' shouldn't be considered a direct object in 'The piano had a stool'.